# Using App Engine default service account credentials to authorize appsmarket api python client

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-apps-marketplace

Why is a custom service account authorized but not the default one?

Why does

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    path_to_custom_service_acc_key, scopes)
authorized_http = credentials.authorize(Http())
build('appsmarket', 'v2', http=authorized_http)
appsmarket_api_client.customerLicense().get(
    applicationId=APPLICATION_ID, customerId=domain).execute()
```

yield correct response but the same code with `path_to_default_service_acc_key` passed yields a `403 Forbidden` error with the message `Not authorized to access the application ID` ?

I tried

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default(
    ).create_scoped(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'])
appsmarket_api_client = build('appsmarket', 'v2',
                              credentials=credentials)
```

too. Yields same error.

Comment: Is the default service account in the same developers console project as the Apps Marketplace listing?

Comment: yes it is...........

Comment: I believe I saw on another thread that the problem was that you hadn't assigned the correct role. Was that it?

Comment: nope. that's not it. the roles assigned are same for both the default and custom accounts.

Comment: Is your error resolved? In fact it may be linked to an earlier issue that happened about earlier and is summarized in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544255/google-marketplace-license-api-suddenly-does-not-work). Also, have you tried the solution concerned with assigning `Can Edit` or `Is Owner` roles to project members, as suggested in the accepted answer?