# Getting "Not authorized to access the application ID" in Google Apps Marketplace API

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I'm trying to list all domain installations of my application.

For this I:

- Published my application privately for the domain;
- Enabled both `Google Apps Marketplace API` and `Apps Marketplace SDK` for my project;
- Configured `Apps Marketplace SDK` (added scope: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license"`);
- Created a service account with the following roles: Project Owner, Project Editor;
- Tried to access API from Java with correctly scoped credentials and failed.

All the time I get the same 403 error:

```
{
    "error": {
         "errors":[{
             "domain": "global",
             "reason": "forbidden",
             "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID"
         }],
         "code":403,"message":"Not authorized to access the application ID"
    }
}
```

Could any one explain what do I miss here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Marketplace license api suddenly does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544255/google-marketplace-license-api-suddenly-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added to more roles: Project Browser and Project Viewer. Either one of them or they both seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. Don't suppose you have any other insights?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was using a Service Account with `Basic Editor` role. Any other less privileged role does not work so it has to be at least Editor or Owner. Then, I had to follow the @A. R. Younce [answer at a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75968178/1188729):

> On the Details tab for the service account, expand the Advanced settings section and click the Create Google Workspace Marketplace-compatible OAuth Client button.

It didn't work right away. I had to wait 20 minutes for this change to propagate.

This is a sample Python Script to test:

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Set the path to your service account key file
KEY_FILE_PATH = 'path/to/service-account.json'

# Set the scopes required for the API
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license']

def create_service():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)
    service = build('appsmarket', 'v2', credentials=credentials, static_discovery=False)
    return service

def list_license_notifications():
    service = create_service()

    # Set your application ID
    application_id = '<application-id>'

    # Set the maximum number of results to retrieve (optional)
    max_results = 100

    # Make the API request
    response = service.licenseNotification().list(
        applicationId=application_id, max_results=max_results
    ).execute()

    # Print the license notifications
    notifications = response.get('notifications', [])
    if notifications:
        for notification in notifications:
            print(notification)
    else:
        print('No license notifications found.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_license_notifications()
```

The Application ID is found at the **[Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project)** page at the **APP CONFIGURATION** tab